# Script to check windows firewall status

Tags: vbscript

I have wrote a script to check windows firewall status. But this doesn't seem to be working. When I run script it shows issue with line 23. But I can't understand what need to be changed and also is this enough to check all other firewall profile as well? Can any one help here please?

```
Option Explicit

'Create Shell object
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'Declare Firewall variables
Dim fwMgr
Dim profile

' Firewall objects have to be created after making sure
' the service is running. If the service isn't running,
' the script will fail.

' Create the firewall manager object.
Set fwMgr = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr")

' Get the current profile for the local firewall policy.
Set profile = fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile

'Verify that the Firewall is enabled. If it is, then disable it.
If profile.FirewallEnabled = True Then
    profile.FirewallEnabled = False
End If
WScript.Echo("tr_FirewallEnabled: " & profile.FirewallEnabled)
```

Comment: And what "issue with line 23" might that be exactly?

Comment: It works for me. Shows the correct value in a message box.

Comment: This script isn´t working in my domain environment, but disabling the firewall on a standalone machine.

Comment: For me on win 8 it requires running as admin; it does not error but does not work in that it pops up an "incompatible version" warning.  investigate using the netsh CLI.